# Is there a character I can use to improve large number legibility in PHP code?

Tags: php, numbers, code-readability, human-readable

In Perl code, you can put underscores in large numbers to improve legibility. For example, the number `123456789` is equivalent to `123_456_789`, which helps the coder understand what number it represents.

Is there a character in PHP that I can use for the same purpose? I have tried commas and underscores, but neither of them work.

Comment: Simple answer, "No"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mark Baker is right, but If you strongly want

```
function f() {
    $f = 0;
    $args = func_get_args();
    foreach ($args as $arg) {
        $f = $f*1000+$arg;
    }
    return($f);
}

$i = f(17,123.81);
echo $i;
```

result `17123.81`

Comment: That is genius! But I don't think I care about in-code readability that much.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot. But why not repeat the number as a comment afterwards with commas?